# Drupal 8 get image filename or URI

Tags: drupal-8

While I would like to find the best way to accomplish this, I'm presently desperate to find any way to accomplish this. I'm trying to get an image filename or URI value inside of a preprocess view function in my theme file but keep hitting roadblocks. The closest I've manage to get is with `$node->field_photo->entity;` and when I dump it I can see the "filename" or "uri" value that I want to get, see screenshot below.

[image]

**Here is what I've tried thus far:**

**#1)** I tried using `$node->field_photo->entity->getFileUri();`

Problem: Returns Error: Call to a member function getFileUri() on null

**#2)** I tried the following:

```
$referenceItem = $node->get('field_photo')->referencedEntities();
$referenceItem[0]->values['filename']
```

Problem: returns null

**#3)** I tried the following:

```
$referencedEntity = $node
  ->get('field_photo')
  ->first()
  ->get('entity')
  ->getTarget()
  ->getValue();
```

Problem: Returns Error: Call to a member function get() on null for " ->get('entity')"

**#4)** I tried getting the image from "target_id" but neither one of the two classes are found:

```
use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media;
```

Problem: Neither class is found

**#5)** I tried the following:

```
// $id = some node ID
// $field = field name for entity reference field
$node = Node::load($id);

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem $referenceItem */
$referenceItem = $node->get($field)->first();

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference $entityReference */
$entityReference = $referenceItem->get('entity');

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter $entityAdapter */
$entityAdapter = $entityReference->getTarget();

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $referencedEntity */
$referencedEntity = $entityAdapter->getValue();
```

Problem:  Error: Call to a member function get() on null for " ->get('entity')"

**#6)** I also tried the following:

```
$node->field_photo->entity->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();
```

Problem: Returns error Call to a member function getFileUri() on null

Comment: It does not really make sense that `$node->field_photo->entity` would return a File object but `$node->field_photo->entity->getFileUri();` would report that getFileUri() was called on null. Unless ofcourse one of the items returned in the view does not have an image/file set. Try checking `$node->field_photo->entity` is not null before calling the getFuleUri() function.

Answer (score 0):

## Short anwser

A dirty and quick way to get the image URI of a Media on Drupal :

```
$media = current($node->get('field_media')->referencedEntities());
$uri = $media->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();
```

## If you want to understand what you've just copy/pasted

It depends of the field name of your image Media type.

Go check in this page : `/admin/structure/media/manage/image/fields` to get the field name.

Assuming that the field name is `field_media_image`, the clean and recommended way to get the image file URI of a Media is :

```php
public function getFileUriFromNode(Node $node) : string {
  // File URI to return (empty string by default).
  $uri = '';
  // Node field media.
  $field_media = $node->get('field_media');
  // Check field not empty.
  if ($field_media->isEmpty() === TRUE) {
    return $uri;
  }
  // Media.
  $media = current($field_media->referencedEntities());
  // File.
  $file = $media->field_media_image->entity;
  // Check file exists.
  if (empty($file) === TRUE) {
    return $uri;
  }
  // File URI.
  $uri = $file->getFileUri();
  return $uri;
}
```

This involves writing more lines of code but ensures that your code never generates a fatal error (error 500), which is, let's face it, good practice.

### Get Drupal Node media image style URI.

To go a little further, if you need to apply an image style (like a resize or else) and then get the image URI with image style applied :

```php
public function getImageStyleUri(Node $node) : string {
  // Image style URI to return (empty string by default).
  $style_uri = '';
  // Same code that above to get media URI first.
  $media_uri = $this->getFileUriFromNode($node);
  // Check media URI.
  if (empty($media_uri) === TRUE) {
    return $style_uri;
  }
  // Load Drupal entity type manager.
  $entityTypeManager = Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  // Load image style by name.
  $style = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('image_style')->load('100x50');
  // Check that image style exists.
   if (empty($style) === TRUE) {
    return $style_uri;
  }
  else {
    $style_uri = $style->buildUrl($uri);
  }
  return $style_uri;
}
```

### Avoid fatal error in PHP 8

> Note that since PHP version 8.0 you can use the null safe operator : https://php.watch/versions/8.0/null-safe-operator

This new operator avoid fatal errors when calling a method on a variable which is not an object with the notation `?->` instead of `->`.

Like this :

```php
// Generate a fatal error if one of these is null : media, field_media_image, entity.
$uri = $media->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();

// Never generate fatal error. Will set $uri with NULL.
$uri = $media?->field_media_image?->entity?->getFileUri();
// The line above does the same that :
if ($media) {
  if ($media->hasField('field_media_image')) {
    if (!$media->get('field_media_image')->isEmpty()) {
      if (method_exists($media->field_media_image->entity, 'getFileUri') {
        return $media->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Quite practical, because it saves time, improves code readability and adds reliability to code execution.